# I want to upgrade grails from 2.3.6 to 2.4.3, but facing issue with plugins

Tags: upgrade, grails-2.4

I'm currently using grails Ver. 2.3.6 and want to upgrade to 2.4.3.

I have dependency of plugins. Some of them are available on grails plugin repository but not all. taggable: 1.1.0 is released but grails repository still shows taggable:1.0.1. I need remaining plugin latest version so that I don't face issue with compilation error.

List of plugin is.

```
plugins {
    compile ':mail:1.0', {
      excludes 'spring-test'
    }
    //compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
    //compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
    compile ":ckeditor:3.6.6.1.1"
    compile ":simple-blog:0.2.1"
    compile ":taggable:1.0.1" // i got this one taggable:1.1.0...
    compile ":aws-sdk:1.6.0"
    compile ":blueprint:1.0.2"
    compile ":compress:0.4"
    compile ":cookie:0.4"
    compile ":commentable:0.8.1"
    compile ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    compile ":feeds:1.6"
    compile ":google-analytics:2.0"
    compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.3"
    compile ":mahout-recommender:0.5.2"
    compile ":mail-on-exception:0.1.1"
    compile ":mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1"
    compile ":remote-pagination:0.3"
    compile ":resources:1.1.6"
    compile ":simple-captcha:0.9.4"
    //compile ":solr:0.2"
    compile ":tomcat:2.1.1"
    compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
    compile ":webxml:1.4.1"
    compile ":quartz:1.0.1"
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
  }
```

Facing issue with some of them like ":mahout-recommender:0.5.2" and more.
Please someone provide me latest version of plugin which supports with grails 2.4.3

Comment: mahout-recommender. mahout-recommender-0.5.2/src/groovy/org/grails/mahout/recommender/MahoutRecommenderSupport.groovy: 34: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder what is the replacement for 2.4.3

Comment: Its just amazingly tedious to upgrade grails to 2.4.3. In my case it feels like it would have been better to stick with old version and skip the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

ApplicationHolder has been removed in grails 2.4, grails.util.Holders should be used instead: http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

According to https://github.com/limcheekin/mahout-recommender the last commit was in 2012, so I don't think the developer of the plugin is active anymore. If you want to use this plugin in grails 2.4 you will probably have to make it compatible yourself.

Comment: Thanks for update and I am trying to do same for mahout-recommender but some classes are missing like import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderBuilder. how can i make it compatible. or any replacement if you can provide me.  Same issue zipped-resources, cached-resources and many more.

Comment: i am making it compatible with myself but facing issue with some classes like. unable to resolve class org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException